# picture/imagine as

Tags: difference

> Picture (one) as (something): To imagine that one is or might be a
>   certain type of person or thing (According to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/picture+(one)+as+(something)))

1. I always **pictured** you as a lawyer when you got older.
2. I lived next to them my whole life—I can't **picture** them as killers!

In these two sentences, if I replace “picture” with “imagine”, would any nuanced meaning be lost?

Answer (score 1):

Would any nuanced meaning be lost? I can't imagine what it would be. "To picture" suggests to me drawing a mental picture of what might or might not be. Isn't that what one does when imagining?

Comment: so no difference at all. :)

Comment: Not that I can tell.

Comment: You may want to wait for some more answers though. Other people may have different opinions. I think there may be more native speakers active during the day. You're welcome.